# Why does my program cause a security warning that it is changing the thread context remotely?

Tags: windows, security, winapi

I'm working on a Fortran application run on Windows. We use the Win32 API for a lot of functionality. In particular, we use `CreateThread` a lot to kick off a computationally-heavy subroutine in the background so the user can keep interacting with the GUI in the mean time. The call looks like this:

```
my_thread = CreateThread(NULL_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,0,LOC(my_subroutine),NULL,0,NULL)
```

Recently, some users have reported that Windows security is giving them a warning whenever our application is run. In particular, it is telling them "application.exe changed the thread context remotely to inject code into application.exe". I can't figure out why this warning is being thrown.

Other places where we use these thread-type API functions are calls to `CloseHandle` or `WaitForSingleObject`. We also have code like:

```
TYPE (T_STARTUPINFO)         :: sival
TYPE (T_PROCESS_INFORMATION) :: pival

call ZeroMemory(LOC(pival),SIZEOF(pival))
call ZeroMemory(LOC(sival),SIZEOF(sival))
sival%cb          = SIZEOF(sival)
sival%dwFlags     = STARTIF_USESHOWWINDOW
sival%wShowWindow = SW_SHOWNORMAL

iret = CreateProcess(path_to_executable,NULL,NULL,NULL,FALSE,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,NULL,NULL,sival,pival)
iret = WaitForSingleObject(pival%hProcess,INFINITE)
```

We're not ever using functions like `SuspendThread`, `WriteProcessMemory`, or `SetThreadContext`.

How could we be causing this security warning and how can we fix it? Is this an issue with us using `NULL_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` in the `CreateThread` call?

I'm not interested in simply getting around or suppressing the warning. I want to make sure I'm creating a secure application our users can trust.

Comment: Do you ever call `CreateRemoteThread`?

Comment: Pure speculation:  I wonder whether the Fortran runtime is injecting code into the thread you created. Perhaps it needs to manage some resources on a per-thread basis. For example, maybe something in the runtime needs to be initialized for each thread.  To ensure this is done even for threads created directly through the WinAPI, they might hook the thread creation event, inject the initialization code, and then restore the thread context.

Comment: @joshpoley we do not ever call that.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy which Fortran runtime would that be? Are you saying it may not even be our code that's doing it? Or maybe I'm misunderstanding. We do use OpenMP extensively, which is manipulating threads on its own.

Comment: Might try placing a breakpoint on `SetThreadContext` (in both kernel32 and kernelbase) to see if it ever gets hit.

Comment: How can I do that in Visual Studio? I know how to set a breakpoint in my code, but I've never done it for an external library.

Comment: I don't know what the issue is; but i'm curious. What is `NULL_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES`? If the goal is to inherit whatever privileges the user running the program has, you're supposed to pass `NULL`. I assume it is a *typed* version of `null`? It looks to me like it's a false-alarm from someone's anti-virus.